# Marklogic: DLS-INVALIDVERSION

Tags: versioning, updating, marklogic, document-management, document-versioning

when trying to access older versions of my managed `XML` files, it gives me something like:

```
DLS-INVALIDVERSION: (err:FOER0000) /company/1448220.xml has no version number 3
in /MarkLogic/dls.xqy, at 1403:6, ...
```

Indeed, the file of version 1, 2, 3 within **/company/1448220_xml_versions** does not exist (in this case lets assume version 4 is the most recent).

When updating a document using `dls` (Document Management) functions, I run the following tasks:

> 1. Check whether the document is managed or not
> 2. When its not managed, set to manage using `dls:document-manage($uri, fn:false())` inside of an eval statement
> 3. Update the document using `dls:document-checkout-update-checkin($uri, $new-doc, "Document
>      update", fn:true())` inside of an eval statement

So far so good.

When tying to get a specific version of a document:

> 1. dls:document-version($document-uri, xs:unsignedInt($version))
>
> ==> When using $version := 4 it gives me a valid document (which in turn is the most recent version)
>
> ==> When using $version := 1 it just gives me an error, indicating that the document of version 1 doesn't exist.

What I am doing wrong?

I am using MarkLogic 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't set a retention policy using `dls:retention-rule-insert`, and the default retention rules retain nothing (which means that `MarkLogic` deletes all older versions of a given document each time you store a new version of it).  See the "**Defining a retention policy**" section in the **MarkLogic Application Developer's Guide**, [here](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls#id_91470).

Comment: That helped me a lot. I have completely ignored these retention rules.